# Equation manipulation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation:

$$2^{x - 1} = \frac{360}{y}$$

I want to manipulate it so that $x$ is on the LHS of the equal sign, all by itself. Do you think I remember how to do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: For starters, take the logarithm.

Comment: I wonder how long our "helpful" users can resist going on, without waiting for Peter to return and show his efforts?

Comment: And you might want to omit all the *noob/need to go back to school/shame on me/do you think I remember* stuff, nobody cares.

Comment: @GEdgar, excellent question but we already know the answer: around 12 minutes.

Comment: @GEdgar: isn't self-deprecation effort enough?!?

Comment: And Peter, no, I do *not* think you remember how to do that.

Comment: All I hear is "blah blah blah I don't have a personality blah blah blah". As you can see below, some people here are useful - you should take note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of dealing "bringing down" variables from exponents is to use logarithms.

The basic properties of the logarithms (either $\log$, the logarithm base 10, or $\ln$, the logarithm base $e$), are:

- $\ln$ is defined only for positive numbers as inputs.
- $\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)$;
- $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$;
- $\ln(a^b) = b\ln(a)$.

So, if you take logarithms on both sides of your equation, you get
$$\begin{align*}
2^{x-1} &= \frac{360}{y}\\
\ln\left(2^{x-1}\right) &= \ln\left(\frac{360}{y}\right)\\
(x-1)\ln(2) &= \ln(360) - \ln(y) \\
x\ln(2) - \ln(2) &= \ln(360) - \ln(y).
\end{align*}$$
I trust that at this point you know how to isolate the $x$...

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. Is there a reason why you chose ln rather than log base 10?

Comment: @Peter: I prefer what is natural to what is common. (-: Logarithm base 2 would be the simplest thing to use here (assuming you have a simple way of computing logarithms base 2), but you can use *any* base.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is take the logarithm base two of both sides, which should leave you with
                       $$x-1=\log_2(360/y)$$
Thus,
                       $$x=\log_2(360/y)+1$$

Hopefully this helps, but more generally and for future reference, when
                      $$a^{f(x,y)} = g(x,y),$$
then
                       $$f(x,y)=\log_ag(x,y).$$